# Get string date from millis with API level 15 with right Locale and 24h

Tags: java, android, date

I stored a Date in sqlite db using INTEGER this:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

And now i'm getting it back into a LONG and after to string with this:

```
myTextView.setText(convertDate(date_in_millis.toString(),"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

using this function

```
    public static String convertDate(String dateInMilliseconds, String dateFormat) {
    return DateFormat.format(dateFormat, Long.parseLong(dateInMilliseconds)).toString();
}
```

I'm in Italy.

Well, first of all i'm losing somewhere hours and minutes.

Second i'm not able to set 24h (with HH instead of hh)

I need to use API level 15 then i cannot use API 24 Libraries and i'm unable to use most answers i found.

Comment: Always try to store and fetch UTC time. Move timezones around on the retrieval side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `Calendar` class:

```
public static String convertDate(String dateInMilliseconds, String dateFormat) {
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(dateInMilliseconds));
c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1); //Work-around to get your lost hour
return df.format(c.getTime());
}
```

And you can use HH to get 24h

Comment: I'm so stupid, sry, "import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;" does not require level 24. I'm trying...

Comment: Rosario, Yes your code works. Anyway i'm losing exactly one hour. I think it's because i have a different UTC.

Comment: I have a work around for that. Check my updated answer

Comment: I tried also to use Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).getTimeInMillis() to save Date. I'm even losing an hour. (Italy is GMT+1) Any idea?

Comment: Thanks, i accepted the answer because my app is now running as my needs. I need anyway to find a way to update hour for any timezone. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please Rosario modify "cal" with "c"

Comment: Calendar.getInstance() requires API level 24

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_486_373_827_327L )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Rome" ) )
       .format(
           DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss" )
                            .withLocale( Locale.ITALY )
       )
```

> 06/02/2017 10:37:07

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The Question and other Answer are outdated. The troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Adding the library to your Android project is well worth the effort. The legacy date-time classes are a mess; avoiding them will save you much grief.

## Using java.time

Convert your integer number that represents a number of milliseconds since the epoch reference date of `1970-01-01-T00:00:00Z` to a `Instant` rather than a `Date` or `Calendar`. Call [`Instant.ofEpochMilli`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-).

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( … );
```

Call `toString` to generate a String representing the date-time value.

> instant.toString(): 2017-02-06T00:07:27.879Z

To see that same moment through the lens of a region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), apply a time zone to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Rome" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString():

You can get the JVM’s [current default time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--). If critical, you should ask the user to confirm. Beware that, like `Locale`, the current default can be changed at any moment, even during runtime, by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault();
```

To generate strings in other formats, you can let java.time automatically localize. To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

You can ask for the JVM’s current default `Locale`. If critical, you should confirm with the user.

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
```

Note that **locale has *nothing* to do with time zone**, completely orthogonal issues, separate and distinct. Time zone determines the wall-clock time. Locale only applies to generating a string for presentation to the user. You could present a date-time in a `Pacific/Auckland` time zone with a Finnish locale, or present a date-time in the `Europe/Rome` with a Thai locale. The title of this Question used the word “Locale” but apparently meant “time zone”.

Example code. In this particular example with this particular formatting pattern, we do not technically need to specify a `Locale`. But better to make a habit of always specifying a `Locale`. If you forget to specify, you implicitly rely on the JVM’s current default Locale which can change at any moment during runtime.

```
Locale l = Locale.ITALY ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( l ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

Or you can specify a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter fCustom = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss" ).withLocale( l ) ;
String output2 = zdt.format( fCustom );
```

See example code [run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/iSqvdM).

> millis: 1486373827327
>
> instant.toString(): 2017-02-06T09:37:07.327Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2017-02-06T10:37:07.327+01:00[Europe/Rome]
>
> output: 06/02/17 10.37
>
> output2: 06/02/2017 10:37:07

## No need to convert number to string

I see no need to convert your count-from-epoch long integer to a string. If you have a `long` or `Long`, just pass the `long` or the `Long`. Converting to, and then from, a `String` adds no value.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Comment: Instead of using the standard libraries available in this JDK, suggesting some third party libraries that may or may not be supported tomorrow is questionable.  While we all should be on JDK 8 that isn't always an option.  While hardly perfect (and we have IBM to curse for that) pointing out JDK 8 and above libraries for an O/S that only supports JDK 7 and some extras is not helpful

Comment: @stdunbar Apparently you are uninformed as to the importance of the java.time classes, built on the history of one of the most-used Java libraries, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Characterizing the legacy date-time classes as “hardly perfect” is a laughable understatement. The legacy classes are a *disaster*, poorly designed, confusing, and flawed. As for “may or may not be supported tomorrow”, the java.time classes went through years of development and are now an official **permanent part of Java**. The back-port is built by members of the same team as java.time.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks a lot for this great reply. Anyway i need to get Locale and TimeZone directly from the device, if possible. You answer should be perfect once this. Thanks again.

Comment: mmmmh... are you sure it is for Android?

Comment: @SteveRogers (A) Regarding Android, reread my Answer. In 2 places I mention using [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) for Android, adapting the ThreeTen-Backport project for Java 6 & 7 from the creators of java.time. And I link to a how-to posting, specific to Android. (B) Regarding getting default locale and time zone, I added code examples for both of those: `Locale.getDefault()` & `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. Beware that the current default can be changed at any moment by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM *during* runtime. Best to ask the user if critical.

Comment: @BasilBourque many thanks, i will take this post in a safe place. At this moment i'm not able to import external libraries but in future sure i will try :-)